# how to change jRecorder accept.php file into servlet file

Tags: php, servlets, jrecorder

please can someone help me to change the jRecorder accept.php file to change to servlet
i dont understant  `file_get_contents('php://input')` to change java

```
    <?php

   if(!isset($_REQUEST['filename']))
   {
     exit('No file');
   }

   $filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];

   $fp = fopen($filename, "wb");

   fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('php://input'));

   fclose($fp);

   exit('done');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually php://input allows you to
read raw POST data.
It is a less memory intensive
alternative to
      $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
and does not need any special php.ini
directives.
php://input is not available with
    enctype="multipart/form-data" .
Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/
wrappers.php.php